# How to run multiple integration tests using mocha recursively without getting their hooks all combined?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I have made a few integration test using mocha which run fine when run independently but when i try to run them using : `mocha test --recursively` .

The behaviour I noticed here is that all the after hooks (probably the before  too) are getting combined.
I drop my db in the `after` hook of each test so I check in between tests and I can find data from the previous tests.

It gets cleared up after the last test somehow.

I have already tried importing them into one file but even that won't serve the purpose.

Here are my hooks.

```
before(async () => {
    app.set('port', SERVER_PORT);
    server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${SERVER_PORT}`));

    // Initial feeding of the database
    await dookie.push('mongodb://localhost:27017/tests', SEEDDATA);

});


after(async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
    server.close();
    process.exit(0);
});
```

***THANKS***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jest as it provides the functionality you're looking for inbuilt.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what is wrong with your tests without having a closer look at the code, so I'm going to drop here a few ideas that come to my mind, with no guarantee that anything will help.

### Possibility 1

Use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` rather than `before` and `after`. This will ensure that your DB cleanup code is executed after each test, rather than after the last test in a `describe` function block. Details [here](https://mochajs.org/#hooks).

### Possibility 2

You are running your tests in multiple threads with mocha-parallel-tests or some other tool. Make sure that the tests where the DB is being accessed are not being parallelized.

### Possibility 3

Your `db.dropDatabase` call returns before the database is actually dropped, while the request is still pending. You'll have to check your connection or database settings.

---

If nothing helps, try inserting log statements at the start of each unit test and before/after hook, this will help you understand when the code is actually being run and see what is happening in the wrong order.